# unable to login with temporary password in B2C log in page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we are having the users in B2C Tenant, and we are log in with admin credentials and
trying to reset the password, it generates the password(temporary password).

when we are trying to log in with user name and temporary password with in Azure Ad Log in page, it shows me,invalid username and password , I have attached the screen shots, please verify and let me know the solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a reset from the Azure portal (using an account with administrator privileges), the temporary password must be changed by the user at the first login.

This issue is similar to another issue you may face when using custom policies in azure AD B2C. The user journey in custom policies doesn't allow the user to change the password at first login, so a generic invalid username and password is returned.

As a rule, when you manage users using API or other interfaces (not through the Azure portal) you must follow the same channel to do every action on users (even for user password reset).

You can verify this using built-in policies. 
Follow this guide ([official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy)) to create (at least) the signinsignup policy (if you don't have one) and push the RUN NOW button inside the policy. You can check that for this user a change password screen will be shown at the first login trial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting for the temporary password to be changed on the next sign-in, then you must create [a sign-in only policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-in-policy).

The sign-in only policy handles this change password scenario by prompting the authenticated user to enter their current (i.e. temporary) and new passwords.

**Note:** The page UI customization feature that is described by [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) is not available to the sign-in only policy.

If the page UI customization feature is important, then you must:

1. Create [a sign-up or sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy).
2. Instruct the new user to "change" their temporary password through the "Forgot your password?" link using [a password reset policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-password-reset-policy).